# Import projection from existing layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, save, project-pane

I work with many different projections and often times find my self working with a projection I do not recognize.

For example, I often times will get a generated CRS I do not recognize

**(* Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=37.08333333333334 +lat_2=38.66666666666666 +lat_0=36.33333333333334 +lon_0=-85.75 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=999999.9999999999 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs))***

Instead of searching for this projection I would like to import the projection from the layer. Arcmap does this in the project tool where you are able to import projections from a layer.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Playing around with this question I have found that you are able to create a spatial index in the properties tab of the layer. This adds the projection to the CRS drop down menu of the save as window which, you can find by following the user number. Has anyone found any other way of importing a projection?

Comment: you can do set project projection from layer